# compare 2 set of object's value

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var x = {name:'james',email:'james@j.com',tel:999};
var y = {name:'james',email:'james@j.com',tel:991};
```

How can I compare above x and y using loop? I'm expecting false because tel is not equal.

tried for in but found it's too messy to maintain later. Sad I couldn't use jquery.

Comment: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the same properties in both objects, like you do above you could do this:

[JsBin Example](https://jsbin.com/wuzivo/3/edit?js,console)

```
var x = {name:'james',email:'james@j.com',tel:999};
var y = {name:'james',email:'james@j.com',tel:991};

for (var prop in x) {
  if (x[prop] !== y[prop]) {
    // do stuff here .. return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, add a check for `hasOwnProperty`. Please.

Comment: Well we dont have the full code to know the prototype chains of each of those two objects. So we can never be sure.

Comment: this is so simple!

Comment: any idea why this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects is so complicated?